# MS Ajax breaks when Response.Redirect is used between two applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I'm currently working on an application that needs to use Windows and Forms authentication (Windows for internal users, Forms for external).  To achieve this I created a small application that grabs Windows users' Domain and Username then redirect to the main application which uses forms authentication.

The applications are hosted as follows:

- http://webserver/passthrough (stores the windows auth data in cookie and redirects)
- http://webserver/app (the main application)

Everything works except for Microsoft Ajax on the main application completely breaks for windows users after the redirect from the passthrough.
If the windows user then closes the browser window and then navigates directly to http://webserver/app in a new session, everything works fine.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I solved this, but it's really not pretty...

I deployed the passthrough application to a separate website running on a different port with the same host header so the deployment now looks like this.

- http://webserver:81/Passthrough
- http://webserver/app

Really not what I wanted to do, but it works.

I vow never to use Microsoft Ajax ever again!